# Add Slides From A Separate PowerPoint File With pywin32

Tags: python, powerpoint, pywin32

I have a list of PowerPoint files and I want to open up each one and insert each of their slides into a single template presentation. Any pywin32 documentation or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax for python. Found it after digging through the depths of the internet

```
template.Slides.InsertFromFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + fileName, template.Slides.Count)
```